# Post call limit of HttpGetRequestStream

Tags: c#, http, post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to figure out whether there is a limit on the call to "GetRequestStream".

To test this, I created a load test with 10 agents and 1 controller all trying to do a post call (object size 10kb) and user count of 10. (code below). I didnt make call to "GetResponse()" to see if i can make large number of calls to GetRequestStream.

But what actually happened was even with all those agents the load test didnt cross 85 ~ 90 Requests per second and the contention point was this line in the code "using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())".

I reduced the agents down to 2 but same result. The end point server is a single server box. When i used a VIP ( backed by 3 servers at the backend), i got 3 times the output i.e was able to go to 270 RPS. 
When i increased the agents again to 15 against VIP, the avg still remained the same. So i concluded there are some shared resources in use during the call to GetRequestStream

Based on an earlier SO post [HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream : What it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325801/httpwebrequest-getrequeststream-what-it-does)

It mentions that the call to GetRequestStream actually blocks some resource at the server end and irrespective of the number of post calls generated, it can only serve so many requests. I used to believe that GetRequestStream doesnt make any call but just gets a stream and writes the object to the stream the call happens when we call GetResponse()

```
HttpWebRequest request =
   (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://some.existing.url");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";

Byte[] documentBytes = GetDocumentBytes ();


using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   requestStream.Write(documentBytes, 0, documentBytes.Length);
   requestStream.Flush();
   requestStream.Close();
}
```

Would really appreciate if someone can point me to some resources where can i dig more detail about this or if someone can explain this behavior.

Comment: More Information found : GetRequestStream sends the headers, waits for a 100-continue, and gives you a stream that writes directly to the network.  Each POST exclusively occupies a connection until you read and close the response. The default connection limit is 2 per uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per http 1.1 RFC, HttpWebRequest has a default connection limit of two from a client to a host – that might cause a drop in latency beyond two concurrent users. It can be changed through the app.config of the client process, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866350/how-can-i-programmatically-remove-the-2-connection-limit-in-webclient) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y.aspx).

Comment: more info : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/1f863f20-09f9-49a5-8eee-17a89b591007